Podman container to run on boot (Microsoft Log Collector)
I have a container for the Microsoft log collector Podman container. In the documentation for the setup it requires the use of this command that I got sucessfully running by itself:
(echo <key>) | podman run --privileged --name PodmanRun -p 601:601/tcp -p 21:21 -p 20000-20099:20000-20099 -e "PUBLICIP='10.0.2.15'" -e "PROXY=" -e "SYSLOG=true" -e "CONSOLE= <tenant>.us3.portal.cloudappsecurity.com" -e "COLLECTOR=PodmanTest" --security-opt apparmor:unconfined --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --restart unless-stopped -a stdin -i mcr.microsoft.com/mcas/logcollector starter

However, I need it to run on boot and I cant get that to work no matter the way I try. Podman allows me to create a systemd unit file but only for the podman command. If I add the key it fails. I also tried running it as a shell script and it doesnt start the container. I think the sub-shell that does (echo <key>) (which seems like an unusual thing to do) is causing the issue. I am unable to find any info on how this subshell works so I can run the podman container on boot.
Does anyone have a sugestion of something to try or an explanetion of how this key works?
The microsoft docs simply say:

Podman containers do not start automatically when the host server is rebooted. Restarting the Podman host machine requires you to start the container again too.

which is not very helpful
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-cloud-apps/discovery-linux-podman
